# How to handle this situatiuon in Perl

Tags: perl

I am having a configuration INI file to store all configuration required for my script to run. I have a Logger.PM which uses Log4Perl, and ConfigReader.PM which reads the INI file and stores the value in global variable. My Start.PL is the entry point where i call the methods from Logger and configreader.

What I do currently

1. In Start.PL I hardcoded the INI file path
2. In Logger.Pm I harcoded the directory name where log files should be stored

What I want

1. I want the INI file path as configurable
2. I want the log folder path to be taken from the INI file

I could do this by following

1. Pass the INI file path as a parameter to the start.pl
2. Read the INI file and get the folder path from INI file

What I could face is that

1. I cannot use the Logger.PM in ConfigReader (partially) since the
   folder name required for logger is part of INI file

I want to log every step of my script (for logging/debugging purpose in case of failure. ) 
I can use `print` but this will write to console and to capture i need to use >>log.txt. Then i will be forced to maintain 2 logs for my application which is not what I wanted

Anyone have a good solution for this scenario?

Comment: It's "Perl", not "PERL".

Answer (score 0):

You can pass INI file path in command line using [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html), and command line switches for istance:

```
Start.pl --ini=/path/to/INI_file
```

Here is a code sample to show what changes are needed in Start.pl, in order to have switches:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.12;
use strict;

use Getopt::Long;

# That little tiny 's' after 'ini=' is for string
GetOptions ( 'ini=s' => \my $ini_file );

say $ini_file;
```

After this change, you can read all options from your INI file, including log folder path ( are you already using a module to manage INI files like [Config::IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Config%3A%3AIniFiles)? ).

There is something still unclear in your question about `print`: although one of my master said that print with a pair of square brackets is the best debugger in the world, why use `print` when you have set up `Log::Log4perl`?

When you say that Logger.PL can't be used in ConfigReader, are you referring to the log object?

Comment: Thanks. I am currently using the the method you described. usage of Print: Since the logger can be initialized only after my config is initialized. If I need to use logging feature inn Config pm, i can use only Print statements,. this is what i meant

Comment: I understand you're worried by something that may fail silently in your `ConfigReader`, but once configuration has been read without errors, nothing else should go wrong in that module. In `ConfigReader` You may add code that stops the whole program ( I mean using `or die "..."` with an error message ) when something fails.

Comment: Yes you are right. But if I use `die` then I need to `print` the message which comes on the screen. Then I need to capture the STDOUT in a separate text file Also this will be a scheduled script.

Comment: If that script is scheduled with cron, terminal output will be mailed to the UNIX user. If that isn't the case, you have to pull out the logger from `ConfigReader`: your logger will be already _online_ when `ConfigReader` runs.

Comment: This one will run on windows. Yes I have to workout something like that but the script will run every 15 mins. Was thinking I could log all things easily in one single log file. Other possibility is that I pass the Log file folder as parameter to the script. Thanks anyway for taking time in expressing your thoughts